# Swift Singleton for preloading Textures in the Delegate not Transferring data to other Classes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, singleton, textures, preload

I am making a SpriteKit game and I am trying to use a singleton to preload all my textures in the AppDelegate so that I can then use the instance of the class with the textures in my game scene later on. The textures are all held correctly in the singleton in the delegate but when I try to get that instance later in my game scene the SKTexture arrays from my singleton are empty. Here is the code in my `AppDelegate`

```
func preLoadAllAssets() {
    var assets = Assets()   //make instance of the assets

    let monkiesAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Monkies")
    let monkiesAtlasLeft = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MonkiesLeft")
    let bananaAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Banana")
    let asteroidAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "SmallAsteroids")
    let asteroidAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MediumAsteroids")
    let asteroidAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "LargeAsteroids")
    let menuAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Menu")

    SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([monkiesAtlas, monkiesAtlasLeft, bananaAnimatedAtlas, asteroidAtlas1, asteroidAtlas2, asteroidAtlas3, menuAtlas], withCompletionHandler: {
            //initialize the different textures
            assets.initAtlases(monkiesAtlas, monkiesAtlasLeft: monkiesAtlasLeft, bananaAnimatedAtlas: bananaAnimatedAtlas, asteroidAtlas1: asteroidAtlas1, asteroidAtlas2: asteroidAtlas2, asteroidAtlas3: asteroidAtlas3, menuAtlas: menuAtlas)
            assets.initMonkies()
            assets.initLeftMonkies()
            assets.initBananaFrames()
            assets.initSmallAsteroids()
            assets.initMediumAsteroids()
            assets.initLargeAsteroids()
            assets.initMenu()
            println("Finished preloading textures")
        })
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])

    //set up the assets
    preLoadAllAssets()

    return true
}
```

Here is my Singleton `Assets`

```
class Assets : SKScene {

static let sharedInstance = Assets()

var monkiesAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var monkiesAtlasLeft = SKTextureAtlas()
var bananaAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var asteroidAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas()
var asteroidAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas()
var asteroidAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas()
var menuAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()

//monkey textures that will be used in the scene
var monkeyTextures:[SKTexture]!
var monkeyLeftTextures:[SKTexture]!
var bananaFrames:[SKTexture]!
var smallAsteroidTextures:[SKTexture]!
var mediumAsteroidTextures:[SKTexture]!
var largeAsteroidTectures:[SKTexture]!
var menuTextures:[SKTexture]!

func initAtlases(monkiesAtlas:SKTextureAtlas, monkiesAtlasLeft:SKTextureAtlas, bananaAnimatedAtlas:SKTextureAtlas, asteroidAtlas1:SKTextureAtlas, asteroidAtlas2:SKTextureAtlas, asteroidAtlas3:SKTextureAtlas, menuAtlas:SKTextureAtlas) {
    self.monkiesAtlas = monkiesAtlas
    self.monkiesAtlasLeft = monkiesAtlasLeft
    self.bananaAnimatedAtlas = bananaAnimatedAtlas
    self.asteroidAtlas1 = asteroidAtlas1
    self.asteroidAtlas2 = asteroidAtlas2
    self.asteroidAtlas3 = asteroidAtlas3
    self.menuAtlas = menuAtlas
}

//init the monkies textures
func initMonkies() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //get textures from the atlas
    //let monkiesAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Monkies")
    var tempMonkeyTextures = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = monkiesAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {                //put all the atlas images into array of textures
        tempMonkeyTextures.append(monkiesAtlas.textureNamed("monkey\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempMonkeyTextures
    self.monkeyTextures = tempMonkeyTextures
}

//init the monkies textures
func initLeftMonkies() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //get textures from the atlas
    //let monkiesAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MonkiesLeft")
    var tempMonkeyTextures = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = monkiesAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {                //put all the atlas images into array of textures
        tempMonkeyTextures.append(monkiesAtlas.textureNamed("MonkeyLeft\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempMonkeyTextures
    self.monkeyLeftTextures = tempMonkeyTextures
}

//set up the banana frames
func initBananaFrames() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //let bananaAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Banana")
    var tempBananaFrames = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = bananaAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {
        tempBananaFrames.append(bananaAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed("banana\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempBananaFrames
    self.bananaFrames = tempBananaFrames
}

//init the asteroids textures
func initSmallAsteroids() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //get textures from the atlas
    //let asteroidAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "SmallAsteroids")
    var tempAsteroidTextures = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = asteroidAtlas1.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {                //put all the atlas images into array of textures
        tempAsteroidTextures.append(asteroidAtlas1.textureNamed("asteroid\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempAsteroidTextures
    self.smallAsteroidTextures = tempAsteroidTextures
}

//init the asteroids textures
func initMediumAsteroids() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //get textures from the atlas
    //let asteroidAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MediumAsteroids")
    var tempAsteroidTextures = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = asteroidAtlas2.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {                //put all the atlas images into array of textures
        tempAsteroidTextures.append(asteroidAtlas2.textureNamed("asteroid\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempAsteroidTextures
    self.mediumAsteroidTextures = tempAsteroidTextures
}

//init the asteroids textures
func initLargeAsteroids() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //get textures from the atlas
    //let asteroidAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "LargeAsteroids")
    var tempAsteroidTextures = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = asteroidAtlas3.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {                //put all the atlas images into array of textures
        tempAsteroidTextures.append(asteroidAtlas3.textureNamed("asteroid\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempAsteroidTextures
    self.largeAsteroidTectures = tempAsteroidTextures
}

//init the menu textures
func initMenu() /*-> [SKTexture]*/ {
    //get textures from the atlas
    //let menuAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Menu")
    var tempMenuTextures = [SKTexture]()
    let numImages = menuAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++ {                //put all the atlas images into array of textures
        tempMenuTextures.append(menuAtlas.textureNamed("menu\(i)"))
    }
    //return tempMenuTextures
    self.menuTextures = tempMenuTextures
}
```

}

and the here is where I use the singleton's `sharedInstance` in my `GameScene`

```
self.monkeyTextures = Assets.sharedInstance.monkeyTextures
self.monkeyLeftTextures = Assets.sharedInstance.monkeyLeftTextures
self.bananaFrames = Assets.sharedInstance.bananaFrames
self.smallAsteroidTextures = Assets.sharedInstance.smallAsteroidTextures
self.mediumAsteroidTextures = Assets.sharedInstance.mediumAsteroidTextures
self.largeAsteroidTextures = Assets.sharedInstance.largeAsteroidTectures
self.menuTextures = Assets.sharedInstance.menuTextures
```

As you can see I am setting `[SKTexture]` variables in my game scene from the singleton. This is when they are empty and the game crashes. What am I doing wrong with my singleton? It is kind of a lot of code so Thank you a ton in advance for the help!

Comment: I do not know Swift but from your description it sounds like you are not passing a reference of your AppDelegate to your Scene.

Comment: I am not passing a reference of the AppDelegate but I am passing the reference of the singleton. I may be wrong but I am pretty sure the point of a singleton is to be able to instantiate it in one class and then use it later in another class just from using the `sharedInstance` object

Comment: Again, I'm not versed in Swift but it looks like you are storing the values in your AppDelegate class and using that as your singleton. If so, you need to pass a reference in order to access the AppDelegate. If not, ignore my comments :)

Comment: Don't I store my atlas properties in my AppDelegate and then store the textures in the singleton when I call all the assets.init methods such as `assets.initMonkies()` ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to have everything load in the AppDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. You could be rejected if your load times are taking too long, or the app will just be killed by the system. You could make a loading scene your first view and load it from a singleton class from there. Also try out this for the singleton.

```
    private let _sharedInstance = Assets()

    class Assets {        
         class var sharedInstance : Assets {
           return _sharedInstance
         } 

    // The rest of your code here
    }
```

Comment: When trying this implementation of the singleton it says that Assets.type does not have a member named _sharedInstance. This is where I got how I am implementing the singleton https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: Updated the code, I misplaced one line, this is exactly how I have it in one working app (save for names). It does not work in the playground, but works in code.